# Compose BasicTextField trailingIcon stretches the heigh of the field

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I ran into an issue today where if I specify a trailing icon for a BasicTextField it forces the height of the field to be increased. Any way to override this setting?
As you can see in the image the 555g field is shorter than the Ingredient1 which became taller due to the addition of the trailingIcon.

[image]

I've tried to understand what's happening in compose and after digging I came across this code in the Google native `TextField.kt`

```
if (trailing != null) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .layoutId(LeadingId)
            .then(IconDefaultSizeModifier),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        trailing()
    }
}
```

So I am inferring from this that `IconDefaultSizeModifier` is forcing the `minHeight` to be 48.dp

and below is the code that I use to create the BasicTextField

```
BasicTextField(
    value = state,
    //... more arguments
    decorationBox = @Composable {
        TextFieldDefaults.OutlinedTextFieldDecorationBox(
            value = textVal,
            visualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
            innerTextField = it,
            singleLine = singleLine,
            enabled = enabled,
            interactionSource = interactionSource,
            trailingIcon = trailingIcon,
            // keep vertical paddings but change the horizontal
            contentPadding = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldWithoutLabelPadding(
                top = 10.dp,
                bottom = 10.dp,
                start = 12.dp,
                end = 8.dp
            ),
            container = {}
          )
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the same height to both TextFields.

Something like:

```
 BasicTextField(
     modifier = Modifier.height(48.dp),
```

[image]

In the same way you can reduce the height.For example

```
 BasicTextField(
     modifier = Modifier.height(32.dp),
     //... more arguments
     decorationBox = @Composable {
         TextFieldDefaults.OutlinedTextFieldDecorationBox(
             contentPadding = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldWithoutLabelPadding(
                 top = 0.dp,
                 bottom = 10.dp,
                 start = 12.dp,
                 end = 0.dp
             ),
```

[image]

Comment: I could do it, but I want to reduce the height to fit more lines....

Comment: @DavidA you can reduce the height in the same way.

Comment: I could do that and it would work but I forgot to mention that I want the text box to wrap text in case of overflow, if I set a fixed height, it no longer wraps text

Comment: @DavidA In this case you can use the `heightIn` modifier or you can use a workaround to add a `trailingIcon` with a `Transparent` tint to the 1st `TextField`.

Comment: Just tried the `heightIn` modifier but it seems to work just like fixed height, if I specify `min` argument it doesn't do anything, if I specify `max` argument it acts like regular `height`

Comment: I'm still interested in this question but with somewhat less urgency, I found a workaround: a bit ugly though, I'm overlaying an icon on top of the `TextField` with a higher Z index